# WOS count in sql

Tags: sql-server

I currently have a projected inventory amount for the next 6 months. I want to count the number of positive values, but want to stop the count once it reaches a negative value, even if there are positive numbers after the negative values.
product
[image: | product| warehouse |date | projected inventory | | -------- | -------------- |-------- | -------------- | | 1 | US |1/1 | 100 | | 1 | US |1/2 | 50 | | 1 | US |1/3 | 0 | | 1 | US |S1/4 | -50 | | 1 | US |1/5 | -100 | | 1 | US |1/6 | 100 | | 1 | US |1/7 | 50 | | 1 | US |1/8 | 50 |]

The sql code needs to state that I have a current projected weeks of supply of 2 since i only have 2 positive projected inventory amounts for initially, even when there are positive values starting 1/6.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to solve your problem we simply need to know the earliest date where the value is negative, then count the positive rows with a date prior to this:

```
select Count(*) 
from Wos
where [date] < (select Min(date) from Wos where Inventory<=0)
```